# How to change the param id in Model.load() (ExtJs)

Tags: extjs, model, load, extjs4

When I define a model "TeMdl" and then use Fn TeMdl.load(1),it will send a request with param id=1.
so..How to Change the id param so the request can like this:"......\?uid=1"?
i am a fresh to extjs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments in the Ext documentation:

The load() method will not honor the idProperty of the Model, and will assume it's "id".

The following subclass fixes this behaviour by using idProperty instead of id.

```
Ext.define("Ux.data.Model", {
  extend: "Ext.data.Model",
  statics: {
    load: function(id, config){
      config = Ext.apply({}, config);

      var params={};
      params[this.prototype.idProperty] = id;

      config = Ext.applyIf(config, {
          action: 'read',
          params: params
      });

      var operation  = Ext.create('Ext.data.Operation', config),
          scope      = config.scope || this,
          record     = null,
          callback;

      callback = function(operation) {
          if (operation.wasSuccessful()) {
              record = operation.getRecords()[0];
              Ext.callback(config.success, scope, [record, operation]);
          } else {
              Ext.callback(config.failure, scope, [record, operation]);
          }
          Ext.callback(config.callback, scope, [record, operation]);
      };

      this.proxy.read(operation, callback, this);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Well,I consider that it make codes more complex, so I drop it and turn to jquery for some ajax request..Thank u all the same :)